# Get value of the Foreign Key in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, foreign-key-relationship

I have a listView populated with data from my db. I use a simpleCursorAdapter to show the values.

I have a table where i can add lessons : English, french...

In another table, i can create lessons developped (i add date of beginning and end, which days, a theme for the lesson). I must provide the lesson as a FK.

When I add a lesson, in my listView i want to show per example : English - Reading, but it shows 1 - Reading. Because 1 is the value i store in my 2nd table.

How can I change 1 to English ?

Here's my code :

```
    Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getAllCours();
    String[] from = { "branche_cours", "designation" }; //here 'branche_cours' is the lesson i store as an INT, it's the FK so
    int[] to = { R.id.text_branche_cours, R.id.text_designation };
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to, 0);
    lvCours.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The method i use getAllCours()

```
public Cursor getAllCours()
{

    //from here, i retrieve the ID, designation and branche_cours
    String Query = ("select ID as _id, date_debut, date_dernier, dixieme_point, " +
            "demi_point, description, designation, lundi, mardi, mercredi, jeudi," +
            " vendredi, samedi, branche_cours from " + TABLE_COURS);

    Open();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

How can I link that int to the real value ( so how can the '1' become 'English')?

Comment: I haven't found the solution yet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to perform an [SQL JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) operation to fetch the data from both tables:

So the SQL query should be something thing like:

```
SELECT table1.branche_cours, table2.designation 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID=table2.ID;
```

Comment: I was testing just like that, and it worked, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

To look up a value in another table, you can use a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

```
SELECT ID AS _id,
       ...,
       samedi,
       (SELECT name
        FROM other_table
        WHERE other_table.id = cours.branche_cours
       ) AS branche_cours
FROM cours;
```